# How can I fix "The package system is broken"?

Tags: 12.04, updates, dependencies

These are the updates:

```
-Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla firefox
-Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla- Unity menubar integration firefox-gobalmenu
-Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla-GNOME support firefox-gnome-support
-Linux kernal image for version 3.5.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP linux-image-3.5.0-gereric (New install)
```

And this is the output:

```
The package system is broken 

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems. 
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

Details:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

linux-image-generic-lts-quantal: Depends: linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic but it is not installed
```

Comment: If you can, upload **all** the output that you get into paste.ubuntu.com and then link it here. Also, take a look at [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/62483)

Comment: Finally, tell us what you get entering `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic` in a terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

a few simple things I would try when this happens: (but I am not an expert...)
- click the Check button again before clicking the install updates button.
- disable ppa's that cause problems (I don't know whether you use a ppa for linux-image-generic-lts-quantal?)
- chose an other Download server under update manager -> settings -> ubuntu Software -> download from: